# How to kill all processes including itself and how to execute all of them properly

Tags: c, unix, process

I'm trying to create a program in C language that runs several processes at FreeBSD and the main goal is to do a web server that,according to some parameters introduced when launching the server, has to control the number of active processes in order to create or destroy them. The thing is that I have some general problems to be resolved that are the following:

-Once I create a number or fixed processes,which I could see that is done correctly, no more processes seem to be created or destroyed, probably because of the while clause but I don't see how can I solve it.

-If I send a SIGTERM, all child processes finish but the parent process.

Here is the code:

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* Here I stablish the routine of signal treatment, including SIGCHLD,
   * and also "starts" the parent process */
  signal (SIGINT, manager_SIGINT);
  signal (SIGTERM, manager_SIGTERM);
  signal (SIGCHLD, manager_SIGCHLD);

  while (end_program != 1)
    {
      sleep (1);
      //Here I control the number of processes and create or destroy as needed        

      /*Here I stablish the signals for the child processes, where they "start" */

      signal (SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
      signal (SIGTERM, manager_child_SIGTERM);
      signal (SIGTERM, manager_SIGTERM);
      while (!end_process)
        {
          //Child processes code is here
        }                       //end while(!end_process)
    }                           //end while(!end_program)
  /* Here I send to all processes the SIGTERM signal and wait its execution*/
  killpg (0, SIGTERM);
  wait (NULL);
  return (0);
}
```

Thanks in advanced,Javier

EDIT:This is how I handle signals

```
void manager_SIGINT(int signal)
{  
end_program = 1;
}

void manager_SIGTERM(int signal)
{   
end_program = 1;
}

void manager_child_SIGTERM(int signal)
{
end_process=1;
}

void manager_SIGCHLD(int signal)
{
pid_t child_pid;
int e;
child_killed_num=0;
do
{
    child_pid=wait3(&e,WNOHANG,NULL);
    if((child_pid>(pid_t)0)&&(WIFEXITED(e)||WIFSIGNALED(e)))
    {
        child_killed[child_killed_num]=child_pid;
        child_killed_num++; 
    }
}while(child_pid>(pid_t)0);
end_process=1;
}
```

EDIT 2: This is how I do the fork:

```
void create_child(int position,ChildTable *table)
{
pid_t child_pid;
    /*Here I block SIGCHLD in something wrong happen when doing fork()*/
sigset_t mask;
sigset_t orig_mask;
struct sigaction act;
memset (&act, 0, sizeof(act));
act.sa_handler = manager_SIGCHLD;
sigaction(SIGCHLD,&act,NULL);
sigemptyset (&mask);
sigaddset (&mask, SIGCHLD);
int is_member=sigismember(&mask,SIGCHLD);
if(is_member==1)
{
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &orig_mask);

fflush(NULL);
switch(child_pid=fork())
{
    case 0:
    {

    }
    default:
    {
        table[position].child.pid=child_pid;
    }
    case -1:
    {
        break;
    }
}
    /*Now that pid has been written it is possible to unblock SIGCHLD*/
    sigdelset (&mask, SIGCHLD);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, &orig_mask);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has no `fork()` in, so how does it launch the child processes? You appear to have nothing left in your example save the signal handling, and you have removed the signal handlers.

The conventional answer to this problem is to maintain an array of the child PIDs when `fork()`-ed, and remove them from the array (and do the `wait`) in the `SIGCHLD` handler. Then on exit you merely need to send a `kill` signal to the processes in the array.

If you want to get fancy, you can also

1. Deal with unexpected termination of the parent (for instance by the children ensuring the parent is alive, perhaps by looking for unexpected closure of a `pipe()`) and exiting if so.
2. Write out a PID file containing the PID of the parent so that the init script can easily deal with killing it off.

However, before you get fancy, I suggest you do something basic.

I suggest you go get / borrow a copy of Stephens: http://tinyurl.com/stephensfaq